# Removing an object inside another object without knowing its depth

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, object

How can I remove an object inside another object, if I don't know it's depth?

**Json Object**

```
{
  "foo": {
     "1" : {
        "bar" : "a",
        "foo" : {
          "2" : "aa"
        }
      },
     "3" : {
        "bar" : "b",
        "foo" : {
          "4" : "bb"
        }
      }
   }
}
```

Let say I want to remove "4", but "4" could have been a first level child or be inside another child?

Comment: To be clear, is this a json string, or a javascript object?

Comment: what should be done if there are multiple 4's (or none at all)?

Comment: anyways, I recommend changing the data structure

Comment: @Jan Dvorak What would you suggest?

Comment: @JasonP this is a Json retreived with $.getJSON

Comment: what is the kind of data you're trying to encode?

Comment: recursively iterate over the structure till you find an object that has a "4" key, and remove it.

Comment: the key (in this example 4) is unique

Comment: Probably something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/z7MPB/

Comment: @SimonArnold can't you move or clone the key to the top object, then?

Comment: @KevinB How can you provide me an example?

Comment: with an answer i suppose. Oh that's probably not what you meant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is another recursive solution, the difference between my version and adeneo's is that mine will stop as soon as a matching key is found.  This is more efficient if you know there won't be multiple occurrences of the same key, or you are okay with only removing one of each occurrence per call:

```
function remove(obj, key) {
    for (var k in obj) {
        if (k == key) {
            delete obj[key];
            return true;
        } else if (typeof obj[k] === "object") {
            if (remove(obj[k], key)) return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explications!

Answer (score 5):

iteration is the key:

```
function remove(obj, key) {
    for (k in obj) {
        if (k==key) {
            delete obj[k];
        }else if (typeof obj[k] === 'object') {
            remove(obj[k], key);
        }
    }
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Bzs7q/)

Comment: Great answer, thumbs up!